# Работа return в php

Tags: php, return

Всем привет. Не могу разобраться, как работает return в php. Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
    function addNumbers($num1, $num2){
        $sum = $num1 + $num2;
        return $sum;
    }
 $result =   addNumbers(10,20);
    echo $result;
$result =   addNumbers(10, $result);
    echo $result;

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Что делает return  в данном примере? Почему не работает, к примеру, вот такой код?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
    function addNumbers($num1, $num2){
        $sum = $num1 + $num2;

    }
$numm  =   addNumbers(10,20);
echo $numm;

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Конструкция return возвращает значения, преимущественно из пользовательских функций, как параметры функционального запроса. При вызове return исполнение пользовательской функции прерывается, а конструкция return возвращает определенные значения.

Если простыми словами то return и есть способ вернуть значение переменной из функции.
При этом код который находиться после return не выполняется.

```
function addNumbers($num1, $num2){
  $sum = $num1 + $num2;
  return $sum;
  $sum+=100;   // Этот код выполнен не будет.
  return $sum; // Этот код выполнен не будет.
};

echo addNumbers(10,20); // возвращенный результат будет 30.
```

Подробней можно почитать по ссылке [function.return.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.return.php)

Answer (score 1):

**[Return](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.return.php)** возвращает результат выполнения функции.

То есть вы отправили 10 и 20 в функцию результат выполнения функции = 30

Второй код, как вы уже могли понять ничего не возвращает ибо не задали что должна вернуть функция и пытаетесь это распечатать

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.